# $\text{dim Hom}(V,V)$ for $V$ a sum of line bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, manifolds, vector-bundles

Let $V$ be a vector bundle given by a direct sum $V=\bigoplus_{i=1}^n L_i$ of $n$ line bundles. The transition functions are then diagonal matrices, which have $n$ free parameters.

Is it also the case that $\text{dim Hom}(V,V)=n$? What is a good way to think about this?

---

**Edit:**

In a comment below, peterag gave a counterexample for the statement that $\text{dim Hom}(V,V)=n$ for $V$ a sum of line bundles.

This being the case, I thought I'd add some additional queries:

1. Are there situations when one would expect $\text{dim Hom}(V,V)=n$?
2. Is this in some sense more likely for a line bundle sum than for a general vector bundle?

Comment: A counter example: suppose the base space is a point. Then one can identify the $L_i$ with one dim vector spaces, and the dimension of ${\rm Hom}(V,V)$ is $n^2$.

Comment: @peterag Thanks for the counter example! Do you happen to also know of any example where a rank $n$ vector bundle $V$ has $\text{dim Hom}(V,V)=n$?

Comment: You might add further tags to your question to get  more intelligent comments than mine:  in what  area are you interested here? e.g  manifolds? alg. geo?

Comment: @peterag Thanks for the tip - those probably are the two other most relevant tags. But I suppose I had some naive idea that the question would be answered in the affirmative, so since you've clearly shown that not to be the case, I'm not sure if I'll get any additional information. Maybe I'll edit to add the additional request for cases where the statement might be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}$If $V = \bigoplus_{i} L_{i}$ is an $n$-fold direct sum, you can identify
$$
\Hom(V, V) = \bigoplus_{i, j} \Hom(L_{i}, L_{j});
$$
the $n^{2}$ summands in the direct sum correspond to the matrix entries in peter's comment.

While $\dim \Hom(L_{i}, L_{j})$ may be finite (e.g., if you're speaking of algebraic or holomorphic bundles over a projective manifold), there's no reason to expect $\dim \Hom(L_{i}, L_{j}) = \delta_{ij}$, so no reason to expect $\dim \Hom(V, V) = n$.

For example, if $H$ denotes the hyperplane bundle over complex projective $m$-space and $L_{i} = H^{i}$, then
$$
\dim\Hom(L_{i}, L_{j}) \simeq \dim\Gamma(L_{-i} \otimes L_{j}) \simeq \dim\Gamma(L_{j - i}) = \binom{m + j - i + 1}{j - i}.
$$

Generally, of course, $\dim\Hom(L_{i}, L_{j})$ can be infinite.